# Ploting and labeling data with variables matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been collecting data from experiments and dumping them into .txt files and I decided to try and write a quick script to plot them with matplotlib. The plotting works fine, but I do not know how to label the plot based on the file name.

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import rc
import sys
import os

rc('text',usetex=True)
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Computer Modern']})


os.chdir(".")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(files,'r')
        temp = []
        for l in f:
            temp.append(float(l))
        plot(temp,labels=files)
        hold(True)


legend(loc='lower left')
hold(False)

# Save the figure in a separate file
savefig('test.png')

# Draw the plot to the screen
show()
```

The problem seems to be with `plot(temp,lables=files)`. If I put `lables=files` I get the error `TypeError: There is no line property "labels"`. If I try and put `labels='files'`, all the plots are labelled files which is useless. Does anyone know how to assign a lable to a plot based on a variable?

Comment: Do not use syntax `from foo import *`. Just do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `label`, not `lables` or `labels`.

```
plot(temp,label = files)
```

Comment: I just tried that and got the error `RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'Reference_9.txt'`

Comment: You can just add a string replace line in your for loop, e.g. `plot( temp, labels = files.replace('_', '-') )`